# Why does the None is getting appended in the list

Tags: python, list, dictionary

In the code below,I want the leaf elements from the dict.

```
group_children_map={'Mould': ['Yeast'], 'Living Organism': ['Animal', 'Plant', 'Mould'], 'Animal': ['Lion', 'Tiger', 'Cat', 'DOG'], 'Plant': ['Tulsi', 'Hibiscus', 'Aloe Vera']}
print group_children_map
node='Living Organism'
leaf_list=[]
def find_leaf(node):
    try_leaf=group_children_map.get(node)
    if try_leaf is None:
        #print node
        return node
    else:
        print try_leaf,"list"
        for l in try_leaf:
            #print l
            leaf_list.append(find_leaf(l))

find_leaf(node)

print leaf_list
```

**Expected output:**

```
['Lion', 'Tiger', 'Cat', 'DOG', 'Tulsi', 'Hibiscus', 'Aloe Vera', 'Yeast']
```

**Actual result:**

```
 ['Lion', 'Tiger', 'Cat', 'DOG', None, 'Tulsi', 'Hibiscus', 'Aloe Vera', None, 'Yeast', None]
```

why None is getting appended in the list...need help :/

Comment: `None` is returned from `find_leaf()` in `leaf_list.append(find_leaf())`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `find_leaf()` function does not always explicitly return something. When the function just ends `None` is returned instead.

The function will only return something if `try_leaf is None` is true. When that's false, you recursively call `find_leaf()`, but after those recursive calls you don't return anything explicitly.

You could explicitly test for that case:

```
for l in try_leaf:
    leaf = find_leaf(l)
    if leaf is not None:
        leaf_list.append(leaf)
```

or instead move appending to the `leaf_list` to the other branch of your code, instead of returning:

```
def find_leaf(node):
    if node not in group_children:
        leaf_list.append(node)
    else:
        for l in group_children[node]:
            find_leaf(l)
```

Answer (score 0):

@Martin Pieters already provided your answer just a little addon if you want to use the method without appending none

**code**

```
group_children_map={'Mould': ['Yeast'], 'Living Organism': ['Animal', 'Plant', 'Mould'], 'Animal': ['Lion', 'Tiger', 'Cat', 'DOG'], 'Plant': ['Tulsi', 'Hibiscus', 'Aloe Vera']}
print group_children_map
node='Living Organism'
leaf_list=[]
def find_leaf(node):
    try_leaf=group_children_map.get(node)
    if try_leaf is None:
        return node
    else:
        print try_leaf,"list"
        for l in try_leaf:
            print l,
            leaf_list.extend(group_children_map[l]) #added the list where the dictionary keys matches

find_leaf(node)

print leaf_list
```